# How to initialize a struct which has a pointer-type property？

Tags: go

The struct is like this:

```
type Node struct {
    Stat *Stat
}


type Stat struct {
    StatInfo []string
}
```

Initialize the structure, and set properties.

```
node := new(Node)
node.Stat.Statinfo=strings.Split(somestr," ")
```

program calls panic:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Comment: The default value of `node.Stat` is `nil` since it is a pointer. You need to initialize it before using it. eg: add `node.Stat = new(Stat)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a struct, it's fields default to [the zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of their corresponding type. It's `0` for `int`, `nil` for pointer fields, etc.

In your case, the only field `Stat` is a pointer, after calling `new(Node)`, `node.Stat` is `nil`, so it would result in the runtime error you see.

To avoid the error, make sure you initialize the fields before accessing them.